# Trying to append my fetched JSON data to a field but this doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to loop through my JSON and then append each word to `col-md-9` with the id `eenwoordlol[ + ID123 +]`, but this doesn't work.

```
var ID123 = 0;

function createExercise(json) {
  const exercises = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;
  exercises.forEach(function(exercise) {
  console.log(exercise.word);

var exer = ($('<div/>', {
    'class': 'row'
}));

var mainCol3 = ($('<div/>', {
    'class' : 'col-md-3'
})).append($('<div/>', {
    'class': 'row'
})).append($('<div/>', {
    'class': 'col-md-3'
})).append($('<div/>', {
    'class': 'col-md-9',
    'id' : 'eenwoordlol[' + ID123 + ']'
}));

var mainCol9 = ($('<div/>', {
    'class': 'col-md-9'
}));

$('#eenwoordlol').val(exercise.word);

exer.append(mainCol3);
exer.append(mainCol9);
exer.append('<br/>');
$("#exerciseField").append(exer);
 });
}
```

The HTML code:

```
<div class="exerciseField" id="exerciseField">

</div> <!-- end of exerciseField-->
```

The `console.log()` does show that I have a word in my JSON file (I know the looping works and it does fetch, but I can't seem to display it), but it doesn't show any given error. So what am I missing out on?

Comment: What are the contents of your json file?  Are you sure you want `.main_object.main_object.exercises` instead of just `.main_object.exercises`?

Comment: Yes I am sure :) It loops successfully through my JSON and displays it on the console.log, but I cannot seem to append what I am looping through on the desired ID. would you like to see my JSON content?

Comment: That's what I meant by "what are the contents of your json file?", yeah :)  It's best to include all the information necessary for others to run your code.   Doesn't need to be the full JSON file, just the parts relevant to this code.    It looks like the issue is that you're trying to set a `val()` on `#eenworldlol`.  `val()` is for input fields, other dom elements need `text()` or `html()`; and that specific element doesn't appear to exist.  You probably want instead to append the word to the dom nodes you're constructing in the rest of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four problems:

- `.val()` is for input fields and textareas; to insert text into a regular dom node use `.text()` or `.html()`.
- You were trying to set `val()` on a nonexistent DOM node '#eenwordlol'.
- You never increment the ID variable, resulting in duplicate IDs.
- Something isn't right in how you're constructing those DOM nodes. EDIT: I've updated this to match your described intended structure:

> Create a main row with col 3 and col 9, within the col 3 I create another row with col 3 and col 9 (on the col 9 the word would be append and the col 3 an audio button) and then I have a col 9 left and within that I wanted to create 4 times a col 3

```js
var ID123 = 0; // You probably don't want to use a global variable for this, but let that slide for now
var fakejson = { // extrapolating this based on the code
  main_object: {
    main_object: {
      exercises: [{
          word: "one"
        },
        {
          word: "two"
        },
        {
          word: "three"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

function createExercise(json) {
  const exercises = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;
  exercises.forEach(function(exercise) {
    var exer = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'row'
      })
      .append(
        $('<div/>', {
          'class': 'col-md-3'
        })
        .append(
          $('<div/>', {
            'class': 'row'
          })
          .append($('<div>', {
            class: 'col-md-3',
            text: "(button here)"
          }))
          .append($('<div>', {
            class: 'col-md-9',
            'id': 'eenwoordlol[' + ID123 + ']', // note the brackets will need to be escaped in later DOM queries
            text: exercise.word
          }))
        )
      ).append(
        $('<div>', {
          class: 'col-md-9',
          text: "(4 x col-3 here)"
        })
      );

    $("#exerciseField").append(exer);
    ID123++;
  });
}

createExercise(fakejson);
```

```css
div {
  /* Just to make structure visible */
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="exerciseField" id="exerciseField">

</div>
```

To be honest, that's a complicated enough structure that instead of carefully nesting all those `.append()` rules you might be better off just writing out the html string directly:

```
var exer = $('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-3">' + exercise.word + '</div>...etc...</div>');
```

If the `eenwoordlol[...]` IDs are only used for the text insertion in this function, you can safely remove them, since the text can instead just be inserted when the node is constructed.

Comment: OH JOOPIE. IT WORKS, sorry I responded so late haha. But I still appreciate the effort put into it! thumbs up vote up!

Comment: what I tried to do with the DOM elements was: Create a main row with col 3 and col 9, within the col 3 I create another row with col 3 and col 9 (on the col 9 the word would be append and the col 3 an audio button) and then I have a col 9 left and within that I wanted to create 4 times a col 3. Or isn't this possible with to create with DOM elements? Since you said some was overwriting the other. Either my code wasn't put together very well or it isn't possible(?)

Comment: Any structure is *possible*; I'm not sure I followed your description of what you want though.   (I shouldn't have said "overwriting", that was a poor choice of words on my part. I thought your nesting of rows-within-rows was unintentional.)

Comment: No haha, that was meant to do so. So the structure I had was / is possible?

Comment: I've updated the answer above to (I think?) match what you described in your comment, yeah.

Comment: oh oops, my bad, didn't pay attention. It's exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate the time and effort put into this a lot @Daniel Beck. My grattitude towards you is immeasurable. Thank you.

Comment: No trouble, happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

`$('#eenwoordlol')` will not find anything because the actual id is `#eenwoordlol[0]`. If you want to select this in a css selector you need to escape the brackets.

Also `val` is used for inputs, use `text()` to set text content:

```
$('#eenwoordlol\[0\]').text(exercise.word);
```

However, this will not work because the element is not even in the DOM, yet. I suggest adding a variable, instead of appending immediately and performing a second lookup later:

```
var content = $('<div/>', {
    'class': 'col-md-9',
    'id' : 'eenwoordlol[' + ID123 + ']'
});
content.text(exercise.word);

var mainCol3 = ($('<div/>', {
    'class' : 'col-md-3'
})).append($('<div/>', {
    'class': 'row'
})).append($('<div/>', {
    'class': 'col-md-3'
})).append(content);

var mainCol9 = ($('<div/>', {
    'class': 'col-md-9'
}));
```

Comment: However the element with that id is not in the dom yet when that code is executed.

Comment: Will this work if I implement more words? --> If I want to fetch more words. Or will it always append to counter 0 and that's it

Comment: @James indeed, I did not catch that, will adapt my answer

Comment: @D.Sof I changed my answer to not use a selector in the first place but just put the text into the element when creating it. That will work with as many words as you want (well, until the browser breaks from the huge page that is ;) ) The other answer is better though, and it is runnable.